# Capture by value with reference parameter modifies captured variable outside expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

When capturing hello as a reference, I expect to be able to modify hello outside my lambda function, but the following code ends with the same hello.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  char hello[] = {"Hello, World!"};

  auto up = [&, hello] (char c) {
      if (!isupper(c))
      {
          c = toupper(c);
      }
  };
  for_each(hello, hello + sizeof(hello), up);

  cout<<hello<<endl;
}

Hello, World!
```

When passing hello by value with c as a reference parameter, I get my expected result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  char hello[] = {"Hello, World!"};

  auto up = [hello] (char& c) {
      if (!isupper(c))
      {
          c = toupper(c);
      }
  };
  for_each(hello, hello + sizeof(hello), up);

  cout<<hello<<endl;
}

cout<<hello<<endl;

HELLO, WORLD!
```

My understanding is when hello is captured by value, up will get a local copy of hello. Implying that whether c is a reference or not hello will not be modified. But in my example c is acting as a reference to the non-local copy of hello. I feel as if I'm missing something fundamental with references.

Comment: Neither of your lambdas make any use of the captured entities.

Comment: Your understanding of lambda captures is completely wrong. Neither of the lambdas you showed uses `hello`, therefore whether you're capturing it by value or by reference (and in both cases you're capturing it by value) makes absolutely no difference, whatsoever. The only thing your lambdas need to capture are objects that your lambdas refer.  Nothing in your lambdas refer to `hello`, as such how you capture `hello` makes any difference.

Comment: By the way, there is no reason to check `!isupper(c)`, since `toupper` will do that check for you, and simply return the character unmodified if it's not a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiled, your lambda expressions aren't actually capturing anything, so you might as well write:

```
auto up = [] (char c) {
  if (!isupper(c))
  {
      c = toupper(c);
  }
};
```

But, even if you do use `[&]`, how do you think the compile knows that `c` is part of `hello`? Couldn't `c` just as easily be part of `goodbye`?

You can think of using `&c` as telling the compiler which array `c` belongs to.

Also, you're working in C++, these raw arrays are not recommended there. This is, perhaps, a better way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  std::string hello = {{"Hello, World!"}};

  auto up = [hello] (char& c) { c = toupper(c); };
  for_each(hello.begin(), hello.end(), up);

  cout<<hello<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I was assuming too much from capture groups. As the above comments stated, I'm not using them in my expression. I overlooked that for_each handles passing c into up.